# manifest.json matches <all_urls> not working after publishing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

From my extension's manifest.json file I am using this:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "content_script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
```

When I install my extension locally the matches: is set to all_urls and everything works as expected.  My content_script is injected for locally opened file:///c:...whatever.html files which is what I want.

When I publish my app to the Chrome Store and install my extension it does not work anymore.  Upon closer inspection I see the Google store has somehow tried to escape my all_urls and my manifest.json is now:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "content_script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
```

Why?  this completely breaks my extension.  How does someone specify all_urls then?  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or why this is happening and appreciate any help someone can provide.

Comment: \u003 is the unicode command for a less than sign, but it's not coming from my manifest.json.  The Chrome Store upload is doing it for some reason.

Comment: Published extensions can't access local files by default for the obvious security reasons. Users have to enable the corresponding checkbox in the extension's detail on chrome://extensions page. As for `\u003C` it doesn't change anything so it's not relevant here. It doesn't appear normally, though, so there's probably something weird in the method you upload the extension.

Comment: I see, I need a way to automatically enable "Allow access to file URLs" upon my extension's installation.  There should be a way to allow this, its up to the user to determine if its acceptable or not.  As long as its shown as being done when installed.  Why is this restricted?

Comment: You want published extensions to have access to the entire user file system by default? Uhm... No. Not gonna happen.